# Python 3 how to make NewRelic async record_custom_metrics calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, newrelic

I want to make the record_custom_metric call from the NewRelic Python module asynchronously. Is there a way to do it?

My idea is to be able to finish my process without having to wait for return/callbacks so using the Python multiprocessing.Pool should not solve my problem (correct me if I'm wrong)